# how to resolve UnsupportedOperationException Required method destroyItem was not overridden

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Though I have override `destroyItem(...)` in `PagerAdapter` getting an error while sliding pages in `ViewPager`

> UnsupportedOperationException Required method destroyItem was not
>   overridden

**Java code**

```
public class PropertyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private int layoutId;
    private List<AddPropertyInfo> dataList;

    public PropertyPagerAdapter(Context context,
            int resourceId, List<AddPropertyInfo> objects) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        _context = context;
        layoutId = resourceId;
        dataList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return v == ((View) obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View pagerView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, false);
        TextView propertyNameTxtView = (TextView) pagerView.
                findViewById(R.id.propertyNameTxtView);
        TextView netIncomeTxtView = (TextView) pagerView.
                findViewById(R.id.netIncomeTxtView);
        TextView netIncomeValueTxtView = (TextView) pagerView.
                findViewById(R.id.netIncomeValueTxtView);
        TextView netExpTxtView = (TextView) pagerView.
                findViewById(R.id.netExpTxtView);
        TextView netExpValueTxtView = (TextView) pagerView.
                findViewById(R.id.netExpValueTxtView);
        TextView netProfitTxtView = (TextView) pagerView.
                findViewById(R.id.netProfitTxtView);
        TextView netProfitValueTxtView = (TextView) pagerView.
                findViewById(R.id.netProfitValueTxtView);

        propertyNameTxtView.setTypeface(Utils.getRegularTypeface(_context));
        netIncomeTxtView.setTypeface(Utils.getRegularTypeface(_context));
        netIncomeValueTxtView.setTypeface(Utils.getRegularTypeface(_context));
        netExpTxtView.setTypeface(Utils.getRegularTypeface(_context));
        netExpValueTxtView.setTypeface(Utils.getRegularTypeface(_context));
        netProfitTxtView.setTypeface(Utils.getRegularTypeface(_context));
        netProfitValueTxtView.setTypeface(Utils.getRegularTypeface(_context));

        String propertyName = "";
        double netIncomeVal;
        double netExpVal;
        double netProfitVal;

        AddPropertyInfo addPropertyInfo = dataList.get(position);
        netIncomeVal = addPropertyInfo.getIncomeAmnt();
        netExpVal = addPropertyInfo.getExpAmnt();
        netProfitVal = netIncomeVal - netExpVal;
        propertyName = addPropertyInfo.getPropertyName();

        String netIncomeValStr = String.format("%.2f", netIncomeVal);
        String netExpValStr = String.format("%.2f", netExpVal);
        String netProfitValStr = String.format("%.2f", netProfitVal);

        propertyNameTxtView.setText(propertyName);
        netIncomeValueTxtView.setText(_context.getResources().
                getString(R.string.doller) + netIncomeValStr);
        netExpValueTxtView.setText(_context.getResources().
                getString(R.string.doller) + netExpValStr);
        netProfitValueTxtView.setText(_context.getResources().
                getString(R.string.doller) + netProfitValStr);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(pagerView);

        return pagerView;
    }
}
```

**Error log**

```
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093): Process: com.teklabs.portfoliomanagenent, PID: 27093
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Required method destroyItem was not overridden
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.destroyItem(PagerAdapter.java:192)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.destroyItem(PagerAdapter.java:124)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at com.teklabs.portfoliomanagenent.adapter.PropertyPagerAdapter.destroyItem(PropertyPagerAdapter.java:47)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1002)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
10-30 18:59:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27093):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Don't call the super. Remove

```
  super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
```

An extract of the PagerAdapter source code

```
123    public void More ...destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
124        destroyItem((View) container, position, object);
125    }

191    public void More ...destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
192        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Required method destroyItem was not overridden");
193    }
```

Comment: That's true, do not call super.destroyItem, I also encountered this problem.

Comment: `super.destroyItem` only works on `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: @Blackbelt Can I ask you how do you browse through the Android source code? Android Studio even now seems so poorly equipped for that, it always complains of some missing source code, and then when you install it it crashes...etc

Comment: Removing super method call worked

Answer (score 38):

Just override:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
     ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you override destroyItem, you should remove the object got in the parameter from its container(also got in parameters). You can cast it to the corresponding View type. 
Here it is:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
}
```

Comment: the exception appears for calling `super`